# regular expression is not working as expected in data annotations (may be syntax issue)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

The DataAnnotations validator not working in asp.net mvc 4 razor view, when using the special characters in the regular expression.

The regular expression pattern I want to use is <\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a>. This catches html tags, but allow & and - symbols on http://regexstorm.net/tester.

However, any character is triggered with the validation.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*<[^>]+>).*", ErrorMessage = "Html tags are not allowed.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

This catches html tags well, but it catches as well as & or -. I want to allow those symbols.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*<[^>]+>).*", ErrorMessage = "Html tags are not allowed.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

Found out that this pattern "^(?!.*<[^>]+>).*" catches html tags and also allow & and - symbols, but somehow the validation trigger with any character.

I need the regular expression pattern that catches html tags and allow & and - symbols.

Answer (score 0):

please add example for what you need to match with regex

Comment: An example to match with regex is <a>test</a> any html tags. but "hello test - this is great example &" this shouldn't match because I don't regex to match the symbols & and -